# SQL query by time too slow

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, optimization

I have a database of 700,000 entries with a fast-text search table. Each row has a time of day associated with it.  I need to page records 100 rows at a time efficiently.  I am doing this by tracking the end of day.

It is taking much too long to execute (15 seconds)

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Objects o, FTSObjects f
WHERE f.rowid = o.AutoIncID AND 
  o.TimeStamp > '2012-07-11 14:24:16.582' AND 
  o.TimeStamp <= '2012-07-12 04:00:00.000' AND 
  o.Name='GPSHistory' 
ORDER BY o.TimeStamp 
LIMIT 100
```

The timestamp field is indexed.

I think this is because the `Order By` statement is sorting all the records returned, then doing a limit but I am not sure.

Suggestions?

Comment: An index on `Timestamp` is my suggestion.

Comment: Timestamp is indexed @Matthew

Comment: A join syntax might also help here `JOIN FTSObjects f ON f.rowid = o.AutoIncID`, but I think the optimizer does that for you already.

Comment: I would like to know how long the fetch of the 100 Object rows takes when isolated from FTSObjects -- i.e. before that join occurs. `select o.autoincid from Objects o where o.timestamp....<snip> and o.name='GPSHistory' order by o.timestamp limit 100` when you have a composite index on `(timestamp,name)` and the original simple index on `timestamp` has been removed.

Comment: Also, how many records are typically fetched by your datetime-range? Are you fetching a little over 100 records, or thousands of records? Also, conversely, are you guaranteed to find at least 100 GPSHistory records by this time-range approach?

Comment: When selecting the 100 Object rows with a composite index on (timestamp,name) select ONLY the `autoincid` at first, no other columns.  If those 100 autoincids come back quickly you can try a "keyset" approach with an inline view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BEST way is to get a good DBA to look at the plan that is generated and make sure it's the most optimal plan (e.g. make sure there are no table scans in the plan, which can happen if the optimizer uses bad statistics)

Here's some things that may help:

- Add an index on `Objects.Name` - possibly even a compound index on `Name` and `TimeStamp`.
- Add an index on `rowid` in `FTSObjects` it it doesn't already exist
- `UPDATE STATISTICS` on the `Timestamp` index periodically (ideally after large updates or daily if updates are continuous)
- Rebuild your clustered index (if you have one).  This would help if your clustered index is on a field that does not get sequential inserts (e.g. a char field where inserts are in random places)
- Don't `select *` if you don't need to - that increases I/O time

You *might* also try casting the strings to `DATETIME`, although I think SQL does this implicitly versus casting the data to a string (which would not use the index on datetime)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Objects o, FTSObjects f
WHERE f.rowid = o.AutoIncID AND 
  o.TimeStamp > CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-07-11 14:24:16.582') AND 
  o.TimeStamp <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-07-12 04:00:00.000') AND 
  o.Name='GPSHistory' 
ORDER BY o.TimeStamp 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I think our SQLite implementation accepts DateTime arguments but just uses strings internally... not sure on that.
Your suggestion of having a DBA look into it made me look into using EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN command.  This let me see a bad index was being used. The classname column was indexed, but there are only 6 unique names.  I got the query to use the Timestamp as an index and now things are about 15x faster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `ORDER BY` is processed before the `LIMIT`, but that's the correct functionality. Paging wouldn't actually work otherwise. But some ideas for optimization.

1. Don't `SELECT *` if it's not absolutely necessary. I **feel** like it's probably not because if you're paging results it's almost certainly not every field in **both** tables the user is looking at.
2. Create a covered index on `AutoIncID, TimeStamp` to keep it from reading the data page. Add `Name` to that index if it comes from `Objects`.
3. Create a covered index on `rowid, Name`, **if `Name` comes from `FTSObjects`**.
4. If the returned fields can be limited, consider adding those fields to the covered indexes **if it's only a couple fields**. You don't want the index to get too big because then it will affect write times.

Comment: The solution had to do with using the wrong index.  The classname column only had six unique names, and was indexed.  I forced use of the timestamp index and now pages are gathered in under 1 second. I tried creating covered indices but they didn't seem to improve things...